# How to add data to manytomanyfield in drf

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCkgP.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1tDE.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mn8Vv.jpg)

So I have a 2 models with a manytomany field. A book might be created without a publisher. When a publisher is added, I want to add it to the Books model with respect to its id any help is much appreciated

Comment: Please add your code to the question instead of images of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose **A** is ManyToManyField and **AA** is the model, then -

First crate the instance:

```
Object = AA.object.create(validated_data)
```

then:

```
Object.A.add(value_to_be_added)
```

Now this is the guess work. Write your code for a detailed answer.

You can also use **remove** method to remove data from manytomanyfield.